# Is there an alternative to a WPF WrapPanel that wraps after a certain number of items, not a height?

Tags: wpf, wrappanel

Normally a WPF `WrapPanel` (Orientation="Vertical") will stack items vertically (and grow vertically) until it runs out of space from the parent container, and then it will "wrap" to the next column.

I want this functionality, but I want to add a hard limit to the number of items in a column.  For instance, if my height is 100 and I have 3 items that are 30 pixels high, normally it could fit them all without wrapping.  However, say I want to force it to wrap after 2.  In that case, I want it to only grow to a height of 60, and wrap the 3rd item into the second column.

Is there something I can do to make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can do it with the [UniformGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.aspx).
Use the [Rows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.rows.aspx) property to definie the amount of elements in vertical direction.

Comment: This works, with the exception that it lays out in the Horizontal direction, and there's no way to override that.

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://www.wpfdude.com/articles/LayoutPanels.aspx) is a nice little article about the available layout panels in WPF.  If one of these does not fit the bill, you might have to build your own custom panel, [here](http://sachabarber.net/?p=229) is a decent demo.